# How does sll in MIPS makes calculations easier compared to direct mult and div?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to understand how SLL will help me perform complex calculations in MIPS.

For example, how is, where I have to keep track of bits:

```
sll $t1, $t0, 3    // essentially $t1 = $t0 * 8
```

Better than (other than the extra assignment):

```
addi $t2,$zero,8
mult $t1, $t0, $t2
```

Comment: Shifting is much cheaper (like 1 cycle, the same cost as `add`) than a general multiply, especially on older CPUs that didn't have the transistor budget for huge pipelined multipliers.  Also, the actual `mult` instruction writes results to the special `hi` / `lo` registers, so you need to get them out with `mflo`.  Using `$t1` as a destination is at best a pseudo-instruction, unless you're using MIPS32 `mul` instead.  (If I'm remembering correctly).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier .  Even modern x86 CPUs have 3 cycle latency for multiply, although fully pipelined at 1/clock.  vs. 1 cycle latency for shifts, with 2 or more per clock throughput.  Earlier x86 had much slower multiplies but still fast shifts, just like early MIPS.

Comment: See also Raymond Chen's article: [The MIPS R4000, part 3: Multiplication, division, and the temperamental HI and LO registers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180404-00/?p=98435)

Comment: it's exactly like when you do operations by hand in decimal. Multiplication by powers of 10 are done cheaply by "shifting" zeros in or out. No one does 45*1000 by doing a real multiplication. In binary 10₂ = 2₁₀ so the same thing happens: multiplication/division by powers of 2 are cheap

Comment: You have already hit on the fact that MIPS does not have a multiply (or divide) by constant/immediate instruction form, so to use them you must materialize the constant (e.g. 8) in a register; whereas MIPS does allow shift left by constant/immedaite, which can substitute for multiplication by a power of 2.  In addition, the program substituting shift for multiply will likely run faster especially on embedded and low power implementations, and maybe save some power as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biggest reason is simple: It's much faster to bit shift than to multiply. This is true for pretty much every CPU. That's the only part that's "easier" really, it's harder to write using bit shifts but is more efficient than a `mult` or `div`. Even with optimizations off, most C compilers will use bit shifts and adds rather than hardware multiplication.

Keep in mind, however, that there is still the possibility for signed overflow when left-shifting. If, in your first example, `$t0` contained `0x7FFFFFFF`,then you'd end up with `0xFFFFFFF8` or `-8` in `$1` after shifting three times.

Comment: Integer multiply can also overflow.  Except when it's widening, like MIPS `mult` where the machine instruction actually writes the HI:LO register pair.  This pseudo-instruction is probably truncating the result to one register-width, so it could overflow, too.  The 2nd paragraph of you answer isn't a difference between shift and multiply, and it's unrelated to performance.  I'm not sure if the question is asking *why* shifts are faster than multiply (i.e. easier for the hardware to do quickly), or what level of detail they're looking for in that.

Comment: I think the question wasn't so much "why is it faster to bit shift", rather "it's easier for me to write `mult` so why go through the trouble of doing a bunch of bit shifts?"

Comment: Yeah, on 2nd look I think they probably read something about shifting being "easier" (for the hardware) and misinterpreted the statement as "easier for the programmer".  But they're not even talking about doing a "bunch of shifts", they're talking about one, for a power-of-2 multiplier where it's completely trivial for people that know binary.  (Depending on the target, real compilers these days use at most 2 shifts or LEA, since modern CPUs have fast multipliers; tuning options can change that some.  https://godbolt.org/z/33xe9hfPa)